# Merge two legends (size and color) into one

Tags: r, ggplot2

What is the code to make the two legends into one: A circles legend with color?

I think, a single legend with circles colored according to "size" and "# total number of crimes" is the best way to show the legend.

Desired output:

1) There should be one legend: the circles, instead of black should be colored: 0 circle = "yellow" to 800 circle = "red".

[image]

#### My code:

```
library(maps)
library(ggmap)
```

#### Get map from Google Maps

```
 lima <- get_map(location = "lima", zoom = 11, maptype = c("terrain"))
```

#### Plot

```
ggmap(lima) + geom_point(data = limanov2, aes(x = LONGITUD , y = LATITUD, color = TOTALES,
                                                  size = TOTALES)) +
        scale_size_continuous(name = "Cantidad\ndelitos",range = c(2,12)) + 
        scale_color_gradient(name = "Cantidad\ndelitos", low = "yellow", high = "red") +
        theme(legend.text= element_text(size=14)) +
        ggtitle("TOTAL DELITOS - LIMA NOV 2012") +
        theme(plot.title = element_text(size = 12, vjust=2, family="Verdana", face="italic"),
               legend.position = 'left')
```

#### My data:

```
    structure(list(DISTRITO = c("SAN JUAN DE LURIGANCHO", "CALLAO", 
"LOS OLIVOS", "ATE", "LIMA", "SAN MARTIN DE PORRES", "SANTIAGO DE SURCO", 
"CHORILLOS", "COMAS", "INDEPENDENCIA", "EL AGUSTINO", "LA VICTORIA", 
"SAN JUAN DE MIRAFLORES", "VILLA EL SALVADOR", "SAN MIGUEL", 
"CARABAYLLO", "MIRAFLORES", "SAN BORJA", "VENTANILLA", "SURQUILLO", 
"BREÑA", "ANCON", "PTE. PIEDRA", "RIMAC", "BARRANCO", "LA MOLINA", 
"SAN LUIS", "SANTA ANITA", "LURIGANCHO", "P. LIBRE", "MAGDALENA DEL MAR", 
"LA PERLA", "CHACLACAYO", "PUENTE PIEDRA", "SAN ISIDRO", "JESUS MARIA", 
"BELLAVISTA", "LINCE", "CARMEN DE LA LEGUA REYNOSO", "CIENEGUILLA", 
"SANTA ROSA", "LURIN", "PUNTA NEGRA", "PUCUSANA", "LA PUNTA", 
"PUNTA HERMOSA", "PACHACAMAC", "SAN BARTOLO", "SANTA MARIA"), 
    TOTALES = c(861L, 696L, 696L, 642L, 516L, 479L, 442L, 378L, 
    371L, 368L, 361L, 333L, 325L, 291L, 282L, 251L, 239L, 196L, 
    193L, 188L, 185L, 174L, 165L, 161L, 138L, 134L, 128L, 119L, 
    115L, 105L, 67L, 65L, 63L, 58L, 58L, 56L, 45L, 38L, 23L, 
    23L, 11L, 8L, 6L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 0L, 0L), HOMICIDIOS = c(1L, 
    7L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 7L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 
    0L, 0L, 7L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 4L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L), LESIONES = c(100L, 72L, 61L, 43L, 44L, 8L, 10L, 
    15L, 44L, 40L, 50L, 15L, 52L, 28L, 7L, 33L, 15L, 3L, 21L, 
    7L, 36L, 33L, 15L, 19L, 14L, 1L, 8L, 6L, 16L, 4L, 4L, 9L, 
    1L, 12L, 2L, 9L, 5L, 2L, 5L, 7L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L), VIO..DE.LA.LIBERTAD.PERSONAL = c(0L, 7L, 6L, 
    5L, 6L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
    1L, 1L, 0L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
    0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L), VIO..DE.LA.LIBERTAD.SEXUAL = c(56L, 14L, 12L, 15L, 7L, 
    10L, 2L, 9L, 11L, 13L, 8L, 9L, 7L, 14L, 4L, 15L, 4L, 2L, 
    17L, 7L, 3L, 4L, 6L, 12L, 2L, 1L, 5L, 3L, 11L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 
    0L, 6L, 2L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 2L, 2L, 0L, 4L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L), HURTO.SIMPLE.Y.AGRAVADO = c(217L, 203L, 296L, 230L, 
    260L, 167L, 226L, 217L, 130L, 117L, 154L, 133L, 121L, 46L, 
    163L, 72L, 161L, 119L, 69L, 120L, 64L, 19L, 64L, 21L, 57L, 
    44L, 39L, 2L, 48L, 60L, 30L, 19L, 48L, 20L, 41L, 25L, 19L, 
    27L, 7L, 11L, 9L, 0L, 6L, 0L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 0L, 0L), ROBO.SIMPLE.Y.AGRAVADO = c(460L, 
    289L, 308L, 344L, 186L, 277L, 198L, 130L, 165L, 184L, 137L, 
    149L, 134L, 188L, 104L, 126L, 58L, 72L, 64L, 51L, 77L, 115L, 
    79L, 76L, 64L, 88L, 73L, 108L, 40L, 36L, 30L, 32L, 14L, 17L, 
    12L, 22L, 12L, 8L, 6L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
    0L), MICRO.COM.DE.DROGAS = c(26L, 100L, 13L, 3L, 10L, 15L, 
    5L, 5L, 11L, 8L, 3L, 23L, 9L, 15L, 3L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 8L, 2L, 
    5L, 0L, 0L, 28L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 2L, 0L, 2L, 
    0L, 0L, 6L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L
    ), TENENCIA.ILEGAL.DE.ARMAS = c(1L, 4L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 
    1L, 0L, 1L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 6L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), LONGITUD = c(-77, 
    -77.12, -77.08, -76.89, -77.04, -77.09, -76.99, -77.01, -77.05, 
    -77.05, -77, -77.02, -76.97, -76.94, -77.09, -76.99, -77.03, 
    -77, -77.13, -77.01, -77.05, -77.11, -77.08, -76.7, -77.02, 
    -76.92, -77, -76.96, -76.86, -77.06, -77.07, -77.12, -76.76, 
    -77.08, -77.03, -77.05, -77.11, -77.04, -77.09, -76.78, -77.16, 
    -76.81, -76.73, -76.77, -77.16, -76.76, -76.83, -76.73, -76.77
    ), LATITUD = c(-11.99, -12.04, -11.95, -12.04, -12.06, -12, 
    -12.16, -12.2, -11.93, -11.99, -12.04, -12.08, -12.16, -12.23, 
    -12.08, -11.79, -12.12, -12.1, -11.89, -12.11, -12.06, -11.69, 
    -11.88, -11.94, -12.15, -12.09, -12.08, -12.04, -11.98, -12.08, 
    -12.09, -12.07, -11.99, -11.88, -12.1, -12.08, -12.06, -12.09, 
    -12.04, -12.07, -11.81, -12.24, -12.32, -12.47, -12.07, -12.28, 
    -12.18, -12.38, -12.42)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -49L), .Names = c("DISTRITO", "TOTALES", 
"HOMICIDIOS", "LESIONES", "VIO..DE.LA.LIBERTAD.PERSONAL", "VIO..DE.LA.LIBERTAD.SEXUAL", 
"HURTO.SIMPLE.Y.AGRAVADO", "ROBO.SIMPLE.Y.AGRAVADO", "MICRO.COM.DE.DROGAS", 
"TENENCIA.ILEGAL.DE.ARMAS", "LONGITUD", "LATITUD"))
```

Answer (score 1):

I've found a solution. Reading the documention for [GGPLOT2 V. 0.9](https://cloud.github.com/downloads/hadley/ggplot2/guide-col.pdf)

It is the new function: `guide_legend()` that should be used inside `guides()`.

This is a function that lets you have more control over legend labels.

This is the end code with the resulting output (See the last line):

```
ggmap(lima) + geom_point(data = limanov2, aes(x = LONGITUD , y = LATITUD, color = TOTALES,
                                              size = TOTALES)) +
    scale_size_continuous(name = "Cantidad\ndelitos",range = c(2,12)) + 
    scale_color_gradient(name = "Cantidad\ndelitos", low = "yellow", high = "red") +
    theme(legend.text= element_text(size=14)) +
    ggtitle("TOTAL DELITOS - LIMA NOV 2012") +
    theme(plot.title = element_text(size = 12, vjust=2, family="Verdana", face="italic"),
           legend.position = 'left') +
    guides(colour = guide_legend())
```

[image]